# ORC file format

Tags: hive

I am new to Hive. Could you please let me know  answer for below question?

Why do we need base table while loading the data in ORC?
Can't we directly create table as ORC and load data in it?

Comment: you can directly create table as orc table.

Answer (score 0):

**1. Why do we need base table while loading the data in ORC?**
We need of the base table, because most of the time we get the data file in text file format, i.e. CSV, TXT, DAT or any other delimiter that we can open the file and see the content. But the file Format ORC maintain in a different way by using their algorithm to optimized the Row and Column.
Hence we need of a base table, so, Actually what happened in that case. We create a table with the textFile format and select the data over their and write it into ORC table.

**2. Can't we directly create table as ORC and load data in it?**

Yes, you can load the data into ORC file directly.

To understand more about ORC, you can refer to https://orc.apache.org/docs/

Answer (score 0):

Usually if you don't define file format , for hive it is textfile by default.
Need of base table arises because when you create a hive table with orc format and then trying to load data using command:
load data in path '' ..
it simply moves data from one location to another. 
hive orc table won't understand textfile. that's when serde comes into picture. you define serde while creating table.
so when a operation like :
 1. select * (read)
 2. insert into (write)

serde will serialize and desiarlize various format to orc and map data to hive columns.